# Show that $\tau = \inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}: X_n \in \{a, -b\}\}$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X$ be a symmetric nearest neighbor random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ with $X_0 = 0$ and let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Set $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$. Show that $\tau = \inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}: X_n \in \{a, -b\}\}$ is a stopping time.

My argument looks like this:

$\{\tau \leq n\} = \bigcup_{k=0}^n\{X_k \in \{a,-b\}\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ since $\{X_k \in \{a,-b\}\} \in \mathcal{F}_k \subset \mathcal{F}_n$.

But I'm not sure if there is something missing.

Comment: That's exactly it. In discrete time stopping times are rather simple.

Comment: Alright, thank you! This one-liner gives 3P in the current exercise sheet (which is much compared to other exercises). Thats why I am confused, but thanks for the quick response!